# Selecting JSON Column is taking too much query execution time

Tags: json, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016

I am doing a simple select statement

```
SELECT A.JSON_Data, Col xyz, Col abc
FROM Table A
INNER JOIN Table B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

and what i noticed is that if I am not selecting `A.JSON_Data` it runs in 3 secs else takes 4 minutes if I select `A.JSON_Data`

`A.JSON_Data` is a big JSON Data Column with format like

```
{"name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}
```

I want to increase performance of SQL Query yet want to display `JSON_Data` as it is without splitting/ parsing it into separate columns

Please suggest a way to increase performance

Answer (score 0):

Unless that JSON column is much, much bigger, it sounds really odd that just selecting it makes a 3 second query run in 4 minutes.

One thing to consider thoug: When I'm storing a bunch of JSON data in a database (and same issue for XML data), I don't want to break it all out into separate columns. I get that.

However, there are usually a few columns that are used in most queries.

Instead of having to write the code to break them out on each insert/update, etc. you can create a persisted computed column that has just those values, and then index the persisted computed columns. That avoids you needing to endlessly parse the JSON or XML. But make sure you use PERSISTED so it's only calculated on insert/update, not on every select.